# How can we use android studio's coding features for React native module development

Tags: android, react-native

I have created a RN module. No error there, But i am not getting suggestions and compile time error detection auto complete , references and usage and all.

I have made the module with [create-react-native-library](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-builder-bob)

If I import entire project dir (which includes ios, android dir) then gradle is synced but no features works while coding.

If I only import android directory, it throws errors and sync fails.

Error:
gradleCould not create task ':generateDebugRFile'.
Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method IncrementalTask.taskAction$gradle_core() because interface org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs is not a valid parameter to an action method.

Edit: I was able to fix above error. then it has error as
`Failed to resolve: com.facebook.react:react-native+`

I am looking for a proper way to write code for react native android (java, kotlin)

Answer (score 1):

The error message you provided suggests that there is an issue with using the @TaskAction annotation on the taskAction$gradle_core() method of an IncrementalTask because the IncrementalTaskInputs interface is not a valid parameter for an action method.

1. Android Native Modules : https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android
2. Running a React Native App on Android Studio A Step-by-Step Guide : https://groovetechnology.com/blog/running-a-react-native-app-on-android-studio-a-step-by-step-guide/
3. Dive into React Native for Android Development :
   https://www.toptal.com/react-native/react-native-for-android-development
4. How to integrate Native modules in React Native Apps ? Explained : [https://medium.com/@gopesh.jangid/how-to-integrate-native-modules-in-react-native-apps-explained-355bab3cab90#:~:text=To%20use%20the%20native%20module,name%20from%20the%20specified%20library](https://medium.com/@gopesh.jangid/how-to-integrate-native-modules-in-react-native-apps-explained-355bab3cab90#:%7E:text=To%20use%20the%20native%20module,name%20from%20the%20specified%20library)
5. Could not create task ‘:app:compileDebugKotlin’ : https://discuss.gradle.org/t/could-not-create-task-compiledebugkotlin/46992
6. Import fails with GradleException: Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method IncrementalTask.taskAction$gradle_core() : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-27599/Import-fails-with-GradleException-Cannot-use-TaskAction-annotation-on-method-IncrementalTask.taskActiongradlecore
7. how to solve cannot use taskaction annotation on : https://slack-chats.kotlinlang.org/t/12356096/anyone-know-how-to-solve-cannot-use-taskaction-annotation-on
8. Upgrading your build from Gradle 7.x to 8.0 :
   https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_7.html

Answer (score 0):

Solved and working like charm.

- I upgraded the android studio to latest version.
- I open the RN project (the actuall app project, not module project i was trying to develope)
- Then I let android studio to sync

now my RN module also synced nicley and all features are working fine.

- All features of android works
- Even 'Run App' starts the app (metro must running)
- Android's Logcat feature also works if app is run from android studio.